# How to change the detail view based on the master view

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I am in the process of learning iOS on my own and am currently focusing on implementing my app on the iPad. I am stuck with a particular scenario and I could go about it using a long route, but wanted to check with the more knowledgable folks out there to see if there is some other way to go about this.

Using splitViewController on iPad.

Master view controller is a tab view controller.

tab1 displays a table, tab2 displays a list of images.

If master view is on tab1, based on the row selected in the table, another table is displayed in the detail view. Based on the row selected in the table on the detail view, an image view is displayed in the detail view using segue.

If master view is on tab2, the image view is displayed in the detail view directly.

Everything is OK, except in the following case:

Lets say the master view currently displays tab1, user selects a row in the table and the corresponding table is displayed in the detail view. User now selects tab2 in the master view. I need to display an image view in the detail view (it's currently displaying a table), but it's getting quite messy with pushViewController and I am wondering if is there is something else that could be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate between Tab1 and Tab2 in the Master view. Implement the image viewing alone in the detail view. It doesn't sound correct to me to have tab1 in master, tab2 in detail view AND navigating to the image view from tab 2.